# vsftpd seems to disreguard umask

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp, upload, umask

I configured my `vsftpd` to allow virtual users to upload file. However I wanted all uploaded files to not be downloadable, thus depriving a potential attacker the usefulness of storing his nefarious files.

So I put in my `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`:

```
file_open_mode=0777
anon_umask=0577
local_umask=0577
```

I figured that one of the `*_umask=0577` is superfluous, but it seems to be harmless, and it cover all my bases.

However, when I upload a file, it gets a:

`-rw------ (0600)` permission instead of `--w------ (0200)`.

The questions are: **Why?** and **How to fix this?**.

Incidentally, my current configuration seem to do the correct thing, that is to allow only uploads, and disallow download of uploaded files, but I don't understand why.

---

Just to complete the picture,  I also use:

```
virtual_use_local_privs=NO
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=my_ftp_user
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=my_ftp_user
```

that works fine, and is there to help me enforce global ftp quota.

Answer (score 3):

You say:

> Incidentally, my current configuration seem to do the correct thing, that is to allow only >uploads, and disallow download of uploaded files, but I don't understand why.

I saw this as a problem, which I tracked down to virtual_use_local_privs, I needed virtual_use_local_privs=YES

Using this allowed local_umask and file_open_mode to be used correctly by the virtual users.

Comment: This works like a charm, thx!

Answer (score 1):

I've read many posts and answers looking for a solution to this issue.

Users were uploading files to my vsftpd server but the permissions were not being set correctly.  Specifically I wanted files to be created with a chmod of `664`.

To enable this I tried setting the vsftpd.conf `local_umask` to `0002`.  It did not work.  The group permissions were not set to write in the file uploaded.

I discovered that the umask of the user uploading the file also needed to be set to 0002.

But most importantly, the user umask has to be set by a `umask 0002` command in the user's `~/.bashrc` file.

If you set the umask elsewhere - e.g. in the `~/.bash_profile` file it does not work.